# VBA unfilter each sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with filtered ranges on each sheet. I have tried a couple different methods but when stepping through it only does the first sheet or none at all. This is what I have tried.

```
dim ws as worksheet
For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        Ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    Next Ws
```

- this one isn't doing anything at all

this one is less sophisticated and not what I want.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
Next ws
```

- this is only doing the first worksheet and not moving to the next.
- this is the full code and it is not returning any errors

```
    Sub Cleanup()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim mergedWb As Workbook
    Set mergedWb = Workbooks.Add()
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FolderPath = "<folder path>"
    
    
    
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
    
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
     
        For Each Sheet In wb.Sheets
           Sheet.Copy After:=mergedWb.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
     
        wb.Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    
    Sheets(1).Delete
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
            ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        Next ws
    
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Wss.` be `Ws`?

Comment: What Scott said! And the second attempt is only doing the first sheet because `Rows("1:1").Select` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Select` here. And you need to reference it to the `ws` of the loop: `ws.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter` because the active sheet does never change in the loop. Also avoid using `.Select`.

Comment: Are the worksheets in the workbook containing this code? Are the worksheets filtered with `Autofilter` or `AdvancedFilter` or do they just have hidden rows? Do the worksheets contain Excel tables i.e. list objects and they are filtered?

Comment: @ScottCraner that was a typo on my behalf. It still doesn't work it is reflected in my code as WS. I corrected the post

Comment: @VBasic2008 each sheet is in a folder and then merged into one workbook. When they are imported they already have a filtered applied. No hidden columns or rows. The filter is applied to the headers so they can filter through the rows but no selections are made.

Comment: do you have a `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes I do. this is currently what I have:  `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
On Error Resume Next
    If ws.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        ws.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter = False
    End If
    Next ws`

Comment: @ScottCraner it isn't even doing the first sheet or subsequent sheets with this code

Comment: Remove it and let us know the error and where it occurs.

Comment: Wait, remove the `Rows("1:1")` it is only checking for that row being filtered not the whole.  Just do: `ws.AutoFilter = False`  But still remove the `On Error` line it covers things you should deal with.

Comment: In the `For Each...Next` loop, use the one-liner `If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData`.

Comment: I guess I am not being clear. I apologize. I want to remove the ability to filter all together so they are normal text cells

Comment: Then use `If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I wish I could screen share because I have tried that as well and it is not doing it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your edit. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I guess it was because I used ws = worksheet in a different module. I changed it to a different variable wks =worksheet and it worked lol thank you and everyone for their patience and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Sheets to New Workbook

**Issues**

- `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing this code. It has nothing to do with the code so far: you're adding a new (destination) workbook (`mergedWb`) and you're opening (source) files ('wb') whose sheets (`Sheet`) will be copied. Instead, you should use:

  ```
  For Each ws In mergedWb.Worksheets
  ```
- When you use the *Sheets* collection, you need to keep in mind that it also includes charts. Therefore, you should declare:

  ```
  Dim Sheet As Object
  ```
- You need to qualify the first destination (work)sheet to ensure the correct worksheet is deleted:

  ```
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
      mergedWb.Sheets(1).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  ```
- To turn off the auto filter, you need to use:

  ```
  dws.AutoFilterMode = False
  ```
- You can avoid the loop by copying all sheets (that are not *very hidden*) at once (per workbook):

  ```
  swb.Sheets.Copy After...
  ```
- The line `swb.Sheets.Copy` (no arguments) copies all sheets (that are not *very hidden*) to a new workbook.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cleanup()

    Const SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.xls*"

    If Not CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
            .FolderExists(SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH) Then
        MsgBox "The folder '" & SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim IsNotFirstSourceWorkbook As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName

        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)

        If IsNotFirstSourceWorkbook Then
            swb.Sheets.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
        Else
            swb.Sheets.Copy ' creates a new workbook containing the sheets
            Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
            IsNotFirstSourceWorkbook = True
        End If

        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        sFileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Dim dws As Worksheet

    For Each dws In dwb.Worksheets
        If dws.AutoFilterMode Then dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next dws

    ' Decide what to do with the new workbook e.g.:
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
'        dwb.SaveAs sFolderPath & "CleanUp " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' it has just been saved

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Cleaned up.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I commented above, what seemingly fixed the issue is that in a different module I used `ws=worksheet` by making it different as `wks=worksheet` the code worked using `wks.autofiltermode = false` with the if/then loop